# boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json & Twitter?

Tags: json, boost, twitter, properties, boost-propertytree

I tried real quick as a test to see if I can pipe my twitter feed to boost's JSON parser.  No dice.  My JSON parser cannot handle the following lines:

```
"profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a2.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/4531792\/wallpaper_stock.jpg",
"url":"http:\/\/on.fb.me\/bShBVQ",
exception error: "invalid escape sequence"

"id":86162751646482432,
exception error: "expected value"
```

Removing the offending lines gets a populated property tree.  Obviously not sufficient for twitter.  Here is the code in case I declared my property tree wrong.  Help?

```cpp
int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) 
{
    boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string> pt;
    std::ifstream f;
    f.open("testJSON2a.txt");
    if(!f.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Error";
        return 0;
    }

    try
    {
        boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json(f,pt);
        boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string,std::string>::const_iterator iter = pt.begin(),iterEnd = pt.end();
        for(;iter != iterEnd;++iter)
        {
            std::cout << iter->first << " " << iter->second.get_value<std::string>() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch(boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_parser_error &je)
    {
        std::cout << "Error parsing: " << je.filename() << " on line: " << je.line() << std::endl;
        std::cout << je.message() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the web actually reformatted the uri should be: "url":"http:\/\/on.fb.me\/bShBVQ",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to update to the latest version of boost :-).  Apparently this library is far from stable.  Major changes/refactors in every version.